# Android Studio 3 Canary: Not possible to create Instant App

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

In contradiction to the official documentation it seems it is not possible to create a project with Instant App support. More precisely, the checkbox for Instant App on the "API Levels" page is simply not present. What changed / what should I do differently? It's a clean install of AS 3 Canary, I did not import settings from AS 2.3.

I've created a screenshot: [API Level Choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQZfG.png)

Comment: It is not shown in my `Android Studio 3.0 preview CANARY 5` too. Did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just updating android studio will not work. install Instant app sdK.